# iPhone MKMapView annotations observers selectable once

Tags: iphone, google-maps, annotations, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

I have different custom map annotations on my MKMapView, and when creating the custom view I add an observer and disable the default popup.

At the top of MapViewController.m:

```
static NSString* const ANNOTATION_SELECTED_DESELECTED = @"annotationSelectedOrDeselected";

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // Things here.

    // Enable the view.
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];

    // Delete the default popup.
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:NO];

    // Add an observer on the annotation.
    [annotationView addObserver:self
                     forKeyPath:@"selected"
                        options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                        context:ANNOTATION_SELECTED_DESELECTED];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Then in the observer function, I create the popover and display it:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSString *action = (NSString *)context;

    if ([action isEqualToString:ANNOTATION_SELECTED_DESELECTED]) {
        BOOL annotationSelected = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];

        if (annotationSelected) {
            // Actions when annotation selected.
            // I create the appropriate popover here and display it in self.view
        }
    } else {
        // Actions when annotation deselected.
        NSLog(@"Annotation deselected! But never pass here...");
    }
}
```

My problem is when my popover is dismissed, if I want to select the same annotation, it just doesn't work... Like if the state of the observer is still "activated". So in order to select my annotation, I need to select another one, and then I can select it again... It's annoying to not be able to select the same annotation twice in a row.

Please help me!
Thank you.

Comment: Your code formatting is broken - please reformat to make this more readable.

Comment: I did reformat the code, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `[mapview deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:FALSE];`
I think it work so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:-

```
BOOL annotationSelected = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
```

to

```
BOOL annotationSelected = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew] boolValue];
```

I seem to recall having this problem myself.

Comment: A warning appears with your solution. What I did is deselecting the annotation after the annotation has been selected: [mapView deselectAnnotation:incidentAnnotation animated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

Save the object name passing to the function observeValueForKeyPath as a temporary Object say **oldObject**.

Then write the code given below in function where you are dismissing the popOverView.

[mapView deselectAnnotation:[oldObject annotation] animated:NO];